# Spinner Styling Issue

Tags: android, xamarin

Anybody know why my Android spinners are rending like the following picture. The orange underline is stopping 1/4 of the way across.

[image]

Here is the xml markup

```
<Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner_player_count"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown"/>
```

Comment: You are using the `Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined` style and your spinner is underlined, what visual styling are you trying to achieve?

Comment: The line does not style all the way to the right. For some reason it goes to that lighter orange 1/4 of the way.

Comment: Is there any parent control outside of your `Spinner` that limits its width?